# Corrupted file when creating Word document

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I'm quite new to docx4j. After installing everything, I tried creating an empty .docx file, and  then write text in it. Here's the code :

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("Hello Word!");
wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("HelloWord1.docx"));
```

The file is succesfully created, but when I try to open it with Word 2010, I get an error message saying the file is corrupted. However, when I open it with WordPad, everything is fine, and the text is there. What could I do to solve this problem and open my created documents with Word 2010 ?

EDIT : I converted the corrupted file to zip, here's document.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15" xmlns:ns32="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:ns31="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility" xmlns:ns30="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:odgm="http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy" xmlns:odi="http://opendope.org/components" xmlns:oda="http://opendope.org/answers" xmlns:odq="http://opendope.org/questions" xmlns:odc="http://opendope.org/conditions" xmlns:odx="http://opendope.org/xpaths" xmlns:ns23="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps" xmlns:ns21="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ns17="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">


-<w:body>


-<w:p w14:textId="bde3dbce" w14:paraId="bde3dbce">


-<w:pPr>

<w15:collapsed w:val="false"/>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Hello Word!</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:sectPr>

<w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:code="1" w:h="15840"/>

<w:pgMar w:left="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:right="1440" w:top="1440"/>

</w:sectPr>

</w:body>

</w:document>
```

EDIT 2 : So after hours scratching my head to solve that, I completly uninstalled and deleted all references to docx4j, the re-added the JAR files. For some reason, no more problems after that.

Comment: The answer below is probably the solution to my problem. But does anyone know how I can programatically change the standalone attribute in my XML files ? Any work-around would be greatly appreciated as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this exact code, using the current stable release of docx4j (v3.1) with no issues. A document was created and opened just fine in MS Word 2010. Here's the complete content of my test class, which creates a Word file in a 'test' directory in my C drive (adjust for your machine / OS, obviously):

```
public class PlayDocx4J {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("Hello Word!");
            wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("c:/test/helloword.docx"));
        } catch (Docx4JException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update re XML** having examined the `document.xml` file content you provided, the issue is with the XML declaration in there. As it stands, it throws a corrupt document error in Word. Word also tells you what the problem is (error in line #1, column 54). If you remove the `standalone="true"` attribute, and then paste the edited `document.xml` back into the zip file, it will open without any issue.

This raises the question *why* your generated file contains this declaration (it shouldn't, and I believe the proper value is `standalone="yes"` in any case). The answer must lie with the XML transformer being used in your Java implementation.

(You can read more about this declaration here: http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlquotations/standalone).

Comment: It's really weird. The file is created, and it seems to be fine since WordPad opens it with no problem. Could it be my MS Word version ? I tried cleaning projects, restarting Eclipse and computer... Since this doesn't seem to be a code problem I really have no clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: Weird. I opened the file in Word 2010 just fine. What version of docx4j are you using? Do you have error-trapping around your code? One thing you can do: change the file extension to .zip, open the zip, open the 'word' folder therein, and extract `document.xml` -- paste the content of that as code in your original question, and I'll take a look -- if the file's truly corrupt it should be evident from that.

Comment: I'm also running the last version of docx4j. What do you mean by error-trapping ? I pasted the content of document.xml, hope you will find the solution from there.

Comment: OK, source of the problem found -- see updated answer.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but somehow the problem is still there. I deleted the "standalone" attribute, didn't work. So I tried deleting the "standalone" attributes in ALL the XML files from my docx, still didn't work. I did some tests, and the loading/processing part works fine, I think the corruption happens when the save method is called... Any thoughts on the matter ?

Comment: Yes, your XML processor is adding in the dodgy directive, which renders the resulting dock file corrupt.

Comment: Which Java are you using? (java -version). And which JAXB?